# creating a dynamic assoc array

Tags: php

so basically i created this array to convert an indexed array into a assoc array.

say this is my input array

```
$input = array('this is the title','this is the author','this is the location','this is the quote');
```

and this is my function

```
function dynamicAssocArray($input)
{
    $result = array();
    $assocArrayItems = array('title', 'author', 'location', 'quote');
    $assocItem;

    foreach ($input as $value)
    {
        for ($i=0; $i <= 3; $i++)
        {
            $assocItem = $assocArrayItems[$i];
        }
        $result = $result[$assocItem] = $value;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

im getting this error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'quote'" and the output is string(1) "t"

which i totally do not understand, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You realize `$result` will always set itself to `$result['quote']`, right? If `$result['quote']` is not defined, that will throw an illegal offset error.

Comment: you should change `$result = $result[$assocItem] = $value;` to: `$result[$assocItem] = $value;`

Comment: You loop through `$assocArrayItems` and keep overwriting the value of `$assocItem`. At the end of that loop, `$assocItem` will **always** be 'quote'.

Comment: *Hi, I'm Clippy. It looks like you are trying to reinvent [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine). Do you want me to help you with that?*

Comment: @Matt the value in `$assocItem` is not interesting, only what returns in `$result` is

Comment: if `$result['quote']` isn't defined, `$assocItem`'s value is VERY important (and interesting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function dynamicAssocArray($input)
{
    $result = array();
    $assocArrayItems = array('title', 'author', 'location', 'quote');
    $assocItem;


        for ($i=0; $i <= 3; $i++)
        {
            $assocItem = $assocArrayItems[$i];
            $result[$assocItem] = $input[$i];
        }


    return $result;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(dynamicAssocArray($input));
```

output

```
Array
(
    [title] => this is the title
    [author] => this is the author
    [location] => this is the location
    [quote] => this is the quote
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to initiate variables in php, which renders line `$assocItem;` pointless.
The code below should do the trick.

```
function dynamicAssocArray($input)
{
    $result = array();
    $assocArrayItems = array('title', 'author', 'location', 'quote');

    foreach ($input as $i => $value)
    {
        $assocItem = $assocArrayItems[$i];
        $result[$assocItem] = $value;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

or even better use [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
function dynamicAssocArray($input)
{
    $assocArrayItems = array('title', 'author', 'location', 'quote');
    $result = array_combine($assocArrayItems, $input);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: the array_combinewould work if it is possible to loop through the input array and assign those $assocArrayItems to every 4 elements so after $input[3] or quote => $input[3], it would then start over at $assocArrayItems[0] and keep going  untill the end of $input.

Answer (score 1):

You are

1. overwriting `$assocItem` four times (only leaving the last value in it)
2. assign `$value` to your `$result` array (making it a string).

Do you really need loops? With only four values it's easier to just write it explicitely:

```
function dynamicAssocArray($input)
{
    return array(
      'title' => $input[0],
      'author' => $input[1],
      'author' => $input[2],
      'quote' => $input[3]
    );
}
```

Or, as [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) put it in the comment thread: simply use the builtin [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) function